# relation between log4j and apache.commons.logging

Tags: logging, log4j

Could anybody please tell me 
what's the relation between log4j and apache.commons.logging ? which one is more popular and better ?

I have imported an existing Application in which they have imported `import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;` and written a separate class called `Log` and overridden some of the methods as `critical`, `warn`, `info`

For instance

```
 public static void info(String caller, String toWrite)
   {
      write(caller,toWrite,Log.INFO);
   }
```

Could anybody please tell me is log4j and  apache.commons.logging are different ??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apache Commons Logging is an abstraction for the concrete implementation. It uses log4j, if present and configured. I would use Commons logging in my code and log4j as logging implementation.

Comment: I would use Commons logging in my code and log4j as logging implementation , then why to use Apache Commons Logging ??

Comment: You could use a different or no implementation at runtime, so your program is more flexible.

Answer (score 8):

log4j is a logging framework, i.e. it provides the code to log messages. Commons-logging is an abstraction layer for logging frameworks, it doesn't log anything itself. For example if I write code using commons logging and deploy it on JBoss, the logging is done by log4j, but if I deploy it on WebSphere logging is done by WebSphere's own logging implementation. If I run the same code as a stand alone application it Java's own logging that is used

Answer (score 1):

As per java-doc documentation of commons-logging

Concrete subclass of LogFactory that implements the following algorithm to dynamically select a logging implementation class to instantiate a wrapper for:

- Use a factory configuration attribute named
  org.apache.commons.logging.Log to identify the requested
  implementation class.
- Use the org.apache.commons.logging.Log system property to identify
  the requested implementation class.
- If Log4J is available, return an instance of
  org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.
- If JDK 1.4 or later is available, return an instance of
  org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.
- Otherwise, return an instance of
  org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog

Hence inference is:

- commons-logging is more of abstraction. It can live without LOG4J also.
- If Log4j exists, it chooses it. Otherwise other default available.
- LOG4J is popular because of it's easy redirecting output to a file, and flexibility to configure log levels.

JavaDoc URL: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/javadocs/api-1.1.3/index.html